# QTP 11.0 is not generating systemutil.run command on recording an application

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, qtp, hp-uft

I am using qtp 11.0 32 bit trial version on windows 8.1 pro 64 bit OS. Problem is qtp is not generating the systemutil.run command on recording an application. what the problem would be ? I already tried setting the windows application utility to generate system.util command in tools--> options but still the problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to QTP11's [Product Availability Matrix](http://support.openview.hp.com/selfsolve/document/KM1210389/binary/QTP11.00_ProductAvailableMatrix.pdf) (which you can only see if you have an HP passport and I suppose you don't have considering that you're using a trial version). Windows 8 and 8.1 are not supported with QTP11. This isn't surprising since QTP 11 was released almost two years before Windows 8.

I know for a fact that QTP11 doesn't support IE11 which is the earliest version of IE supported on windows 8.1.

Since you're using a trial version in any case why not download the [latest version (UFT 12)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/unified-functional-testing-automated-testing/demos-documents.html)?

QTP was united with Service Test and is now called Unified Functional Testing (UFT) and version 12 does support Windows 8.1.

Comment: okie thanx... mine is trial version... and ya will get UFT instead... :)